# Redirect program output without changing directory

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

### Problem

I'm writing a set of scripts to help with automated batch job execution on a cluster.
The specific thing I have is a `$OUTPUT_DIR`, and an arbitrary `$COMMAND`.
I would like to execute the `$COMMAND` such that its output ends up in `$OUTPUT_DIR`.
For example, if `COMMAND='cp ./foo ./bar; mv ./bar ./baz'`, I would like to run it such that the end result is equivalent to `cp ./foo ./$OUTPUT_DIR/baz`.
Ideally, the solution would look something like `eval PWD="./$OUTPUT_DIR" $COMMAND`, but that doesn't work.

### Known solutions

[And their problems]

- Editing `$COMMAND`: In most cases the command will be a script, or a compiled C or FORTRAN executable.  Changing the internals of these isn't an option.
- unionfs, aufs, etc.: While this is basically perfect, users running this won't have root, and causing thousands+ of arbitrary mounts seems like a questionable choice.
- copying/ hard/soft links: This might be the solution I will have to use: some variety of actually duplicating the entire content of `./` into `./$OUTPUT_DIR`
- `cd $OUTPUT_DIR; ../$COMMAND` : Fails if `$COMMAND` ever reads files
- pipes : only works if `$COMMAND` doesn't directly work with files; which it usually does

Is there another solution that I'm missing, or is this request actually impossible?

### [EDIT:]Chosen Solution

I'm going to go with something where each object in the directory is symbolic-linked into the output directory, and the command is then run from there.
This has the downside of creating a lot of symbolic links, but it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: A common workaround is to switch to the destination directory, create a symlink to the input file, run the command, remove the symlink.

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!" and [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) "Eval command and security issues".

Comment: I don't entirely understand why it's such a security issue--if a user can call a script that executes their arbitrary code, they can just execute the arbitrary code in the first place.   I can see why you would very much not want to allow it to be run at a higher privilege level though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve this without making some assumptions about the interface of `$COMMAND`. There is no single definition of what "output ends up in `$OUTPUT_DIR`" means. For one program this may be some files, but another program might just print something to stdout and yet another might try sending some data over the internet using some protocol or display something in a GUI and there isn't an obvious way of mapping all of these to "output goes to `$OUTPUT_DIR`".

So, you need to invent some assumptions and require any `$COMMAND` implementation to follow them. Then, it may get as simple as requesting that the command accept a parameter such as `--target=<DIR>`. If your command was some simple command, you would have to create a wrapper script around it to translate that parameter into what the app accepts. `cp`, `mv` and a few more utils already accept the parameter `--target`, so that may be a good starting point.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned the assumption "the command writes files to ./ or a subdirectory".  Either way, your `--target` suggestion is a rather interesting way of doing it that I'd not thought of.

Comment: @zebediah49 If the command is supposed to create files in current directory, there's hardly any other way than actually changing the current dir before command executes (but this has consequences e.g. for reading). One could try and go ahead with tricks like using `LD_PRELOAD` to override system calls such as `open()` in a custom `.so` file and modify the path if file is opened for writing, but that's lots of work and not necessarily reliable (kind of hackish). So, if only possible I'd suggest an interface like in the reply, it's cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set the output directory, you can only set the working directory.

The problem is, once you set the working directory, other references are going to be invalid. For example in your code `foo`:

`cp ./foo ./bar`

If you have a *specific* command, there are workarounds (creating a script that alters arguments, prepending the directory to specific arguments), but in general this is not possible.

Comment: All right, thanks.  That's what I thought, but I was hoping there was some kind of "magic bullet" that I could do at the userspace filesystem level (simultaneously symlinking to two different targets or something).